# fast way to reset 2d jagged array of fixed width

Tags: c#, init, jagged-arrays

I want to create a 2D jagged array (as previous so answers claims is faster on dot net than multidimensional one).

I want to do something like

```
Int [][] myarr = new int [2][3];
```

But `C#` doesn't seem to support this so I did use a for loop for the 2nd dimension instantiation.
Yet if I want to fastly reset I cant use memset equivalent as each new in the loop initiate the array in a possible different and not continouse place.

Is there a faster way to init and reset a fixed width jagged array ?

Comment: There is a `memset` in C#?

Comment: First question that springs to mind here: is that particular part thoroughly measured and real bottleneck in your application?

Comment: Your issue is only O(m) for an mxn array. It's not a bottleneck.

Comment: No. Not at all. It is more theotetical question. I can easily go with loop....

Comment: Well, if it's purely theoretical, then I know of no other way than to clear/reinitialize inner arrays in a loop... But maybe there's some clever trick someone else knows. :)

Comment: There is unmannaged option or something I have seen in abother so question: enumarable.repeate (,).toarray ()

Comment: @scott this is how I create the array. Now I want to reset it "fast".... in multidimensional it should be continouse memory but not here...

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? Do you mean setting all the values back to zero?

Comment: @Dani: Are you using `Array.Clear()` to reset the data without reallocating the arrays? That will be the fastest way.

Comment: @Matthew - This is not an Array object, it's int[][] I don't think it supports clear.

Comment: @Dani I meant to zero each *row* - you can iterate over the outer dimension and call `.Clear()` for each row (each row being an `int[]` which *does* have `Clear()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ and `Enumerable.Range` method, but internally there is still a loop performed:

```
int[][] myarr = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(x => new int[3]).ToArray();
```

Comment: This actually creates a new array rather reset the old one. I guess in dot net it is the same cost ?

Comment: @Dani - usually about the same cost. But for larger arrays, read about the LOH

Comment: I will check it although this is not my case. I need to make a little test to see the costs diff between allocation and reset in a loop.

Comment: I've tested the speed of this - it's the same as a loop. I guess this is the best I can get here. I wonder what happens if I want to set it with value other than 0... anyway, I will use this method, thanks.